# Unity Web Request Post not sending data

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

Unity 2019.2.1f1

I have looked at as many other solutions as I can but none of them seem to solve my issue.

When using UnityWebRequest or WWW to send a WWWForm to a php, the form data never gets read.

Here is the c# code I have using UnityWebRequest:

```
    WWWForm formData = new WWWForm ();
    formData.AddField ("firstname", "firstname");

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post (URL, formData);
    //www.chunkedTransfer = false; //<- Tested with this on and off and no difference
    yield return www.SendWebRequest ();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log (www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log ("Form upload complete!");
        Debug.Log (www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
```

This is what the PHP file looks like:

```
<?php
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    echo "HELLO".$firstname."!!!!";
?>
```

I have also tried using the old way of WWW:

```
    WWWForm formData = new WWWForm ();
    formData.AddField ("firstname", "firstname");
    WWW www = new WWW("test.php",formData);
    yield return www;
    Debug.Log (www.text);
```

The output I get from all of these is: "HELLO!!!!", instead of "HELLOfirstname!!!!".

I have tested the PHP code by sending a form from a HTML file and it worked fine.

Comment: Try `print_r($_REQUEST);` on your PHP.

Comment: WWWForm  is a class.  You need code to extract the text strings from the class and put into your post.

Comment: @BrettGregson that prints out an empty array: "Array{}".

Comment: can you please add this string on your php side: var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));

Comment: @myxaxa this is what it returned: string(0) ""
HELLO!!!!

Comment: have you tried the first example from here - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual//UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html with IMultipartFormSection ?

Comment: More like that for PHP: `$firstname = $_POST['firstname'] ?? ""; echo sprintf('HELLO%s', $firstname);`

Comment: try to print `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to check if the method is POST.  
sometime the problem is trailing slash (and redirect loss the post method and data).

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and did the following:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class pp : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool runReuqest = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (runReuqest)
            StartCoroutine("runRquest");
    }

    IEnumerator runRquest() {
        runReuqest = false;
        // Your Code no changes
        WWWForm formData = new WWWForm();
        formData.AddField("firstname", "firstname");

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://my-ip/j.php", formData);
        //www.chunkedTransfer = false; //<- Tested with this on and off and no difference
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

and I got the log as follows:

```
Log:
Form upload complete!
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

HELLOfirstname!!!!
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

Check if your code is messing up somewhere, or use the above as a guide.

**edit 1**
I didn't get to inspect the previous answer, but it seems to work for me as well.
j.php:
Received: HELLOfirstname!!!!

You might be missing something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had, or have, the same problem, so I am using the following:
The idea here, is to send a field called POST, then have the php script check for POST, with the isset($_POST["POST"])

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("post","POST");  // Added line to check for post
form.AddField("userID", userID);
```

Then, in the php script, I do the following:

```
if (isset($_POST["POST"]) || (isset($_POST["post"])))
{
    echo("You sent a POST.\nPrinting the POST...\n");
    print_r($_POST);
    
    $userID = $_POST["userID"]; 
}
```